# Next 14 with Google recaptcha v3 showing info box on all routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, react-google-recaptcha

I have problem with my project which is written in Next 14. I use npm library https://github.com/snelsi/next-recaptcha-v3 to have Google recaptcha on my contact site. There I have to use recaptcha provider wrapper in my contact page. So that's how it looks:

```
export default async function Contact() {
  return (
    <ReCaptchaProvider>
      <div className="contact-form">
        <ContactForm />
      </div>
    </ReCaptchaProvider>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, something is not working as I would like. When I go to the /contact path a small information box appears in the bottom right corner. Unfortunately, when I change the path, e.g. to /, the box is still displayed. Only when I refresh the page does it disappear.

[image: Google recaptcha info box]

How can I fix it?